# r regex for complex variable splitting problem

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have a `data.table` of variables representing antimicrobial drug resistance gene variants that are all concatenated together for each drug class.

I need to produce a separate binary column for each gene variant, marked as `TRUE` if the gene variant for a given drug class is present and `FALSE` otherwise.

The names of the new variables should be in the format drugclass_genevariantname, where drugclass is inherited from the name of the original variable and genevariantname is a value extracted from a splitting operation with `strsplit`.

The gene variants are separated by a semi-colon `;` so that is the character I have used to split on in the following function, which will return the `data.table` with the new binary columns added on to the end:

```
getamr <- function(dt, amrcol, splitchar) {

    columnvector = dt[[amrcol]]

    if (all(is.na(columnvector))) {return(dt)}

    y = unique(unlist(strsplit(x = columnvector, split = splitchar)))

    y = sort(y)

    for (i in 1:length(y)) {

      dt[, noquote(paste0(amrcol, "_", y[i])) :=
           ifelse(grepl(y[i], columnvector, fixed = TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)]
    }

    return(dt)

  }
```

This function works fine for creating the new columns and identifying if each gene variant is present or not.  However, the names of the gene variants are not being assigned to the new variables correctly because of the complex format, which is something like:

> gene1[position1:oldAA-newAA;position2:oldAA-newAA];gene2[position1:oldAA-newAA];gene3[v];gene4;gene5

In this example, I would expect the following new variables to be created:

- drug1_gene1[position1:oldAA-newAA]
- drug1_gene1[position2:oldAA-newAA]
- drug1_gene2[position1:oldAA-newAA]
- drug1_gene3[v]
- drug1_gene4
- drug1_gene5

The difficulty I'm having is in situations like the first and second case in the bullet points above, where in the original string the split character is inside the square brackets.  This results in:

- drug1_gene1[position1:oldAA-newAA
- drug1_position2:oldAA-newAA]

... which no longer makes sense as in the second case, the variant position and variant changes have been orphaned from the name of the gene in which they occur.

How should I modify the above function to correct the new column names so that:

1. the square brackets are closed in examples like the first case
2. variant positions and changes are always preceded by the gene name

Below is some example data that illustrates the complexity of this problem:

```
# Load data.table:
library(data.table)

# Create example data:
mydt <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 amr_drug1 = c("erm(B)[v];mdf(A)*;mph-(A)*;strA;sat2A", "mdf(A)*;strA;sat2A", "-", "erm(B)[v];mdf(A)*;mph-(A)*;strA;sat2A", "-"), 
                 amr_drug2 = c("-", "aph(6)-Id,strB[v]", "aph(6)-Id,strB[v]", "aph(6)-Id,strB[v]", "-"), 
                 amr_drug3 = c("gyrA_EC2[83:S-L]", "gyrA_EC2[83:S-L;87:D-N];parC_EC2[80:S-I]", "gyrA_EC2[83:S-L;87:D-N];parC_EC2[80:S-I]", "gyrA_EC2[83:S-L]", "-"), 
                 amr_drug4 = c("OXA-1", "OXA-1", "OXA-1", "OXA-1", "OXA-1"),
                 amr_drug5 = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-"))


# Identify AMR columns:
amrcols <- grep("^amr", names(mydt), value = TRUE)

# Replace '-' with NA:
mydt[, c(amrcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == "-", NA_character_, x)), .SDcols = amrcols]

# Apply function across all AMR columns:
for (i in 1:length(amrcols)) { getamr(mydt, amrcols[i], ";") }
```

One of the genes in the third amr column (gyrA_EC2) has two variants enclosed in square brackets - after the split operation the second variant is orphaned from the gene name - see below:

```
> mydt
   id                             amr_drug1         amr_drug2                                amr_drug3 amr_drug4 amr_drug5
1:  1 erm(B)[v];mdf(A)*;mph-(A)*;strA;sat2A              <NA>                         gyrA_EC2[83:S-L]     OXA-1      <NA>
2:  2                    mdf(A)*;strA;sat2A aph(6)-Id,strB[v] gyrA_EC2[83:S-L;87:D-N];parC_EC2[80:S-I]     OXA-1      <NA>
3:  3                                  <NA> aph(6)-Id,strB[v] gyrA_EC2[83:S-L;87:D-N];parC_EC2[80:S-I]     OXA-1      <NA>
4:  4 erm(B)[v];mdf(A)*;mph-(A)*;strA;sat2A aph(6)-Id,strB[v]                         gyrA_EC2[83:S-L]     OXA-1      <NA>
5:  5                                  <NA>              <NA>                                     <NA>     OXA-1      <NA>
   amr_drug1_erm(B)[v] amr_drug1_mdf(A)* amr_drug1_mph-(A)* amr_drug1_sat2A amr_drug1_strA amr_drug2_aph(6)-Id,strB[v]
1:                TRUE              TRUE               TRUE            TRUE           TRUE                       FALSE
2:               FALSE              TRUE              FALSE            TRUE           TRUE                        TRUE
3:               FALSE             FALSE              FALSE           FALSE          FALSE                        TRUE
4:                TRUE              TRUE               TRUE            TRUE           TRUE                        TRUE
5:               FALSE             FALSE              FALSE           FALSE          FALSE                       FALSE
   amr_drug3_87:D-N] amr_drug3_gyrA_EC2[83:S-L amr_drug3_gyrA_EC2[83:S-L] amr_drug3_parC_EC2[80:S-I] amr_drug4_OXA-1
1:             FALSE                      TRUE                       TRUE                      FALSE            TRUE
2:              TRUE                      TRUE                      FALSE                       TRUE            TRUE
3:              TRUE                      TRUE                      FALSE                       TRUE            TRUE
4:             FALSE                      TRUE                       TRUE                      FALSE            TRUE
5:             FALSE                     FALSE                      FALSE                      FALSE            TRUE
```

Any solutions to prevent the second (or subsequent) variants inside the square brackets from being separated from their gene name would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is the _regex_ tag included ?

Comment: @sln I'm guessing that some sort of regular expression will be required to deal with the square brackets - just wasn't able to figure out how to construct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the split function, you could first split only at semi-colons outside of square brackets using a pattern like this:

```
;(?=(?:[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]*\])*[^\[\]]*$)
```

And then, split the strings that have a semi-colon inside in an additionl step, e.g. using `;|\[|\]` as split pattern. Retain the frist result to break-up and rebuild the nested values or similar.

[Regex demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/SmDYPr/1)